# How to override requiresConstraintBasedLayout in UIView using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, constraints, overriding

In the `UIView`, docs, it is stated that you must override `requiresConstraintBasedLayout` to return `true` in your custom view if if needs constraints to work.

How do you do this using Swift 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the following syntax for overriding the getter:

```
override open class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be shortened by omitting the get clause and simply returning true.

Answer (score 2):

To override the `requiresConstraintBasedLayout` getter you can simply use:

```
override open class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
    return true
}
```